# Matching intervals with values in another table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, intervals

Currently, I have one df and a price table.

```
Order Number  wgt           wgt_intvl        price
-------------------         ---------------  -----
 01            22           0-15             50
 02            5            15-25            75
 03            35           25-50            135
```

What I'd like is to match the weight from the df into an interval of the price table in R. For example, the first order (`Order Number 01`) corresponds with a price of 75. Therefore, I want to add a column in the first df, say `df$cost` that corresponds with the appropriate price according to `wgt_intvl` in the price table.

The way I see to do it is with an `if-else` statement, but this is highly inefficient and I was wondering if there is a better way to do it. In reality these tables are much longer - there is no logical "buildup" in price or weight interval. I have 15 weight intervals in this table. My current solution would look like this:

```
If(wgt < 15){
  df$cost <- 50
} else if (wgt > 15 & wgt < 25){ 
  df$cost <- 75
} else if(wgt > 25 & wgt < 50){ 
  df$cost <- 135
}
```

This times fifteen, using the corresponding prices of the price table. I'd love a more efficient solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, form the vector of cutpoints (i.e. the first number in each interval) and then use `findInterval` to find the interval corresponding to the weight.

```
cutpoints <- as.numeric(sub("-.*", "", dfprice$wgt_intvl))
transform(dfmain, price = dfprice$price[findInterval(wgt, cutpoints)])
```

giving:

```
  Order wgt price
1    01  22    75
2    02   5    50
3    03  35   135
4    04  25   135
```

### Note

```
dfmain <- data.frame(Order = c("01", "02", "03", "04"), wgt = c(22, 5, 35, 25), 
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dfprice <- data.frame(wgt_intvl = c("0-15", "15-25", "25-50"), 
 price = c(50, 75, 135), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This satisfies my exact needs. Thanks for that - I'll implement when I have time and come back if there are any issues :)

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that the `dfmain` and `dfprice` in this case are of different length. This means that with this code I'll get the error `arguments imply differing number of rows: 2824, 1381`.

Comment: There is no requirement that the two data frames have the same number of rows. I have modified the example to make them different and the same code works and you can see from the output that I have posted in the question. You must have introduced some other error but we can't tell what it is without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an if-statement you could use a more efficient case_when operation:

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>%
mutate(cost = case_when(
    wgt < 15 ~ 50,
    wgt > 15 & wgt <25 ~ 75,
    TRUE ~ 135))
```

Alternatively you could use `cut()` to transform wgt to wgt_intvl and match via `left_join()`.